# Prove that $\tan\left(\frac{x}2 - \frac{\pi}8\right) = \frac{\sqrt{2} - \cos(x) - \sin(x)}{\sin(x) - \cos(x)}$

Tags: functions, trigonometry

I am studying trigonometry, specifically the following formulas:
$$\sin(a+b), \cos(a+b), \sin(2x), \cos(2x), \tan(a+b), \tan(2x), \tan^2(x),$$
and expressing $\sin(x), \cos(x), \tan(x)$ in terms of $\tan(x/2)$.

Now, I have a specific question: Can anyone provide me with a hint to prove the identity:
$$\tan\left(\frac{x}{2} - \frac{\pi}{8}\right) = \frac{\sqrt{2} - \cos(x) - \sin(x)}{\sin(x) - \cos(x)}$$

This is what I tried:
$$\tan\left(\frac{x}{2} - \frac{\pi}{8}\right) = \frac{\tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) - \tan\left(\frac{\pi}{8}\right)}{1 + \tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) \tan\left(\frac{\pi}{8}\right)}$$
Then, I substituted $\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{8}\right) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{2}} - 1$.
but I don't know what to do

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Its False, but a sign change makes it True.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert half angle to full angle,

$$\tan\frac{t}2=\frac{\sin\frac{t}2}{\cos\frac{t}2}=\frac{\sin\frac{t}2}{\cos\frac{t}2}\cdot\frac{2\sin\frac{t}2}{2\sin\frac{t}2}=\frac{1-\cos t}{\sin t}$$

Let $t=x-\frac{\pi}4$

$$\tan\left(\frac{x}2-\frac{\pi}8\right)=\frac{1-\cos\left( x-\frac{\pi}4\right)}{\sin \left( x-\frac{\pi}4\right)}=\frac{1-\cos x\cos \frac{\pi}4-\sin x\sin \frac{\pi}4}{\sin x\cos\frac{\pi}4-\cos x\sin \frac{\pi}4}$$
therefore,

$$\tan\left(\frac{x}2-\frac{\pi}8\right)=\frac{\sqrt{2} - \cos(x) - \sin(x)}{\sin(x) - \cos(x)}$$

Answer (score 1):

Use the half angle formula

```
Tan[x/2-p/8] == Sqrt[(1-Cos[x-pi/4])/(1+Cos[x-pi/3])]  = 
  (1-Cos[x-pi/4])/Sin[x-pi/4
```

at least for intervals of positivity.